# Difference between local and yarn in hadoop

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have been trying to install Hadoop on a single node following the instructions written [here](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SingleCluster.html). There are two sets of instructions, one for running a MapReduce job locally, and another for YARN.
What is difference between running a MapReduce job locally and running on YARN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use local the map and reduce tasks are run in the same jvm. Usually this mode is used when we want to debug the code. Whereas if we use yarn resource manager which is in MRV2 comes into play and mappers and reducers will run in different nodes and different jvms with in the same node(if it is pseudo distributed mode).